# example of endothermic luminescence?

Tags: energy, heat, light

Someone posed an interesting question to me the other day: is all production of light accompanied by the generation of heat? I have found that the question as posed invites vague answers, so I thought I would restrict the question to the case of chemiluminescence and sharpen the language to the following:

*Is there an example of a spontaneously occuring endothermic chemical reaction which generates light as one of the (possibly many) products?*

Assume for the sake of specificity that the reaction occurs at constant temperature and volume. Conceptually, I am envisioning the following energy diagram:

[image]

where the reaction begins with a system consisting purely of reactants $R$. These reactants are excited to a metastable product state $P^*$, with the energy for the excitation coming from the temperature bath. The meta stable state relaxes to the final product state $P$, emitting a photon $\gamma$ in the process. We then would have an instance of a process where a system simultaneously produces light and *absorbs* heat from its surroundings. Note that this is this case whether the energy of the products (neglecting the photon energy) is greater than the reactants (i.e. $P1$) or lower (i.e. $P2$), since in either case the combined energy of $Pn + \gamma n,\,n=1,2$ is greater than $R$.

So I would like to ask if there is a good example which comes to mind of such a reaction, either for final products $(P1, \gamma 1)$ or $(P2, \gamma 2)$?

Comment: Can you add more context and some of your own findings?

Comment: I did do some preliminary searching, though, not having a chemistry background, it is difficult to come up with the right search queries to find examples. I figured it would be a good question to ask a community of chemistry enthusiasts, since they might be expected to be familiar with a wide variety of different chemical reactions.

Comment: As emission of photons must obey the momentum conservation law, it gives some momentum and related kinetic energy to the emitting atom. Even if this energy is very small, compared to mean thermal kinetic energy, it inevitably creates little heat.

Comment: Interesting question. My first thought was simply no, but it is certainly possible to do a non-chemical version using a heat source, a thermoelectric generator and a red LED. So the desired chemical system has to convert heat energy to light energy, with non-negligible efficiency.

Comment: @Poutnik the question is not whether a photon imparts a momentum kick to the atom upon leaving (though in fact it is also possible that the momentum kick acts to *reduce* the molecule's net momentum), but whether or not the light-producing reaction is accompanied by a net absorption of heat from its surroundings.

Comment: @EdV so you would claim that *no* chemical process exists possessing the energy diagram I describe above?

Comment: *Is all production of light accompanied by the generation of heat?* // Due nonlinearity, momentum decrease leads to lesser KE decrease than the vice versa.

Comment: No, but I do not know of any, for what that is worth. Maybe some chemiluminescence scheme, as you suggested, might do the trick. But the only ones I have heard about produce both light and heat.

Comment: I guess the supposed spontaneous endothermic process may have problems with the 2nd TD law. Delta H would by positive, and due conversion of heat to radiation, Delta S would be negative. Delta G would be positive and spontaneity is ruled out.

Comment: @Poutnik if we begin we a sample of pure reactants *R*, then we begin with very low entropy, so that the production of products *P* results in an increase of entropy which can compensate the increase from conversion of heat to light. Also note that the condition for spontaneity for a constant temperature, constant volume reaction is a decreasing *Helmoltz* free energy *F = U - TS*, not Gibbs free energy *G*.

Comment: I see, U have missed the constant volume condition. But I  am not sure, if TD would be happy with decreasing entropy of environment.

Comment: @Poutnik I did specify the constant volume condition in my question. Regarding your other point, whenever one has a system composed purely of reactants and no products, you will always at a finite temperature spontaneously produce products in some (possibly small) quantity, no matter the energy of the products. The entropy increase per mole of reaction diverges as the concentration of products approaches zero, which more than compensates any entropy decrease associated with the photon generation.

Comment: That is why I said I missed it,otherwise  I would say you have not mentioned it.

Comment: Unless your photon is produced with 100% yield from P* some heat has to be produced. Only a  few types of molecules such as 9-10 diphenyl anthracene appear to have almost 100% fluorescence yield.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some digging around on Google Scholar, I came across the following article:

https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja00499a052

which presents the following class of reactions:

[image]

All of these reactions are endothermic in that they have positive molar enthalpies, and also produce near-infrared light at around 1000 nm. Reaction 1 (i.e. $\ce{R_1} = \ce{H}$) in particular has the following energy diagram:

[image]

The relevant quantities here are:

- $\Delta H_o$, which is the molar enthalpy for the production of the *triplet*, i.e. ground state, $\ce{O2}$ product, and
- $\ce{E}_*(\ce{{}^1O2})$, which is the energy of the photon emitted in the singlet to triplet transition.

Interestingly, the authors appear to be assessing the endo/exothermicity of the reaction by $\Delta H_o$, not $\Delta H_o + \ce{E}_*(\ce{{}^1O2})$ as I argued using the diagram in my question. It seems to me that whether one uses the former or the latter to determine endo/exothermicity of the reaction depends on whether one assumes the emitted photon is absorbed by the temperature bath or if it is extracted and used to perform work. In the former case energy conservation would imply that the $\Delta H_o$ determines the heat absorbed by the bath, and $\Delta H_o + \ce{E}_*(\ce{{}^1O2})$ for the latter.